# http://mycomputer/reports adding/editing Drag Drop doesn't work

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am new to using ssrs.  And I trying to develop a simple report to test it out.  I am used to crystal reprots.

After a whole bunch of problems with installing, I finally just built a brand new VM with Server 2012 standard on it and SQL Server 2012 Enterprise and SSRS native mode (non sharepoint ode)

Finally was able to get the URLs to work from the outside so other network computers to access the report manager(had to open up port 80 on the firewall).

```
So using http://sv1/reports
```

Set up my datasource via the report manager.

Now to the report.  From the same url I create a new report (Blank).  I created a simple query to WROX sample Adventureworks DB for the new dataset to use.  Select * from table

Okay all the columns are there under the datasource.

I can not drag these columns onto the report.

If I try to use the Matrix Wizard under insert as the book is giving an example on.  The "Arrange Fields" screen that comes up.  Also will not let me drag and drop.

I know you are supposed to be able to drag and drop because I see online documentation about it.  the book I bought example says drag and drop fields into "row groups" "columns groups" and "E Values".

It won't let me.

I am using IE 9.0.8112.16421

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ran Windows update on my machine.  It installed ie 10 and other .net updates.  The drag and drop functionality is now there.  So something on my system needed to be updated for it to work.